# .NET 3.5 RSS and XML Stylesheets

Tags: .net-3.5, rss, xslt

Can you add an XML-stylesheet to the RSS feed generated through the new `System.ServiceModel.Syndication` namespace?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this at the top of the page :

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="urlToXSLstyleSheet" version="1.0"?>
```

Comment: After creating the feed as a SyndicationFeed object, it is passed as an argument to the Rss20FeedFormatter and the formatter writes it to the Output stream of the Response obeject.

My issue here is that i don't seem to be able to find a way to add an xml-stylesheet to the generated xml. Come to think about, is it even posible :)?

Comment: But can't you write the above tag I mentioned in the Response, before echoing the formatter ?